# How to use a table in IF statement if does not exist in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have requirement in Oracle where I must first check IF Folder table exists or not and then recheck the Folder table for specific value. If not exists then show error

I get **PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist** on line number 14 because Folder table wasnt available.

```
DECLARE
    own   VARCHAR2(200);
    l_cnt INTEGER;
BEGIN
SELECT sys_context( 'userenv', 'current_schema' ) INTO own FROM dual;
SELECT count(*)
INTO l_cnt
FROM ALL_TABLES
WHERE Table_name = upper('Folder')
AND OWNER        = own;
IF( l_cnt       > 0) THEN
    SELECT count(*)
    INTO l_cnt
    FROM Folder
    Where id = 3;
        IF( l_cnt       > 0) THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Value exists');
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Value does not exist');
        END IF;
ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Folder does not exist');
END IF;
END;
```

Could someone help me on how i can use a table that isnt available in DB for rechecking for data inside an IF statement.

Comment: have you tried to catch the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `SELECT` from a table that does not exist at "compile" time as the PL/SQL engine will check that the table exists and, if it does not, will raise `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`.

If you want to `SELECT` from a table that may or may not exist then you will need to defer executing the statement until run-time by wrapping it in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Additionally, you do not need to check if the table exists first; just try to query the table and catch the exception if it does not exist:

```sql
DECLARE
  l_cnt INTEGER;
  table_does_not_exist EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(table_does_not_exist, -942);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from Folder where id = 3' INTO l_cnt;

  IF (l_cnt > 0) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value exists');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value does not exist');
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN table_does_not_exist THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Folder does not exist');
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BDjipKN5)

Answer (score 1):

You can use *EXECUTE IMMEDIATE* to run the query against the folder table:

```
declare
  own   varchar2(200);
  l_cnt integer;
begin
  select sys_context('userenv',
                    'current_schema')
    into own
    from dual;
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
    from ALL_TABLES
   where Table_name = upper('Folder')
     and OWNER = own;
 if (l_cnt > 0) then
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from Folder where id = 3' into l_cnt;
    if (l_cnt > 0) then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value exists');
    else
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value does not exist');
    end if;
else
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Folder does not exist');
end if;
```

end;

See [Oracle documentation on EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html#GUID-C3245A95-B85B-4280-A01F-12307B108DC8)